# Acrobat DC app and user javascript folder issues

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

Running Acrobat Pro DC 15 I have trouble getting the user javascript path

app.getPath("user","javascript") throws and exception 
app.getPath("app","javascript") returns

/Macintosh HD/Applications/Adobe Acrobat DC/Adobe Acrobat.app/Contents/Resources/JavaScripts/

Note the path contains "Adobe Acrobat.app" which conflicts with the application name - so creating the Javascript subfolder is not possible.

What am i missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

Acrobat doesn't create the folder for you on Mac. Create a folder in the following location and then run the command

```
/Macintosh HD/Users/<<user>>/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Acrobat/DC/JavaScripts/
```

Answer (score 0):

The javascript folder needs to be created manually before this method will work....